# Toggle frame within multiple framesets

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frameset

Following situation:

```
<frameset>
    <frame id="top"></frame>
     <frameset id="innerframe">
        <frame id="nav"></frame>
        <frame id="main">
            <frameset id="homeFrame">
                 <frame id="content"></frame>
                 <frame id="box"></frame>
            </frameset>
        </frame>
     </frameset>
</frameset>
```

(I am not very good at formatting this in SO, bear with me)

I want to toggle (make visible/hidden) the frame **"box"** with javascript by using a link, which is located somewhere in the frame **"nav"**.
I tried via `parent.frames['box']` to access my frame, but no sucess.

How to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more of the javascript code you are using at the moment?

Comment: sure, goes kinda like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y83QM/1/)

Comment: before it gets buried: no ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure (I don't use frames often) but it seems you have to target your box frame different.

```
function toggleFrame(elem) {
    //elem = <a> clicked on
    var fframe = parent.frames['homeFrame'].frames['box'];
    if(fframe.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        fframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        elem.value = 'show';
    }
    else {
        fframe.style.visibility = 'visible';
        elem.value = 'hide';   
    }
```

If this doesn't work it could be because of the nested frameset and than you probably should switch the `var` to something like `var fframe = document.getElementById('box');` or `var fframe = parent.getElementById('box');`